# Dependency Injection: Dependency needs field/member

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection

I have two classes A and B. Currently, B is constructed inside of A. Since I want to verify in my unit tests that A calls B's methods correctly, I want to **inject B into A** instead to enable mocking.

The problem is: Upon construction, **B needs one of A's fields** as a constructor parameter. Which means that if I inject B and therefore move its construction out of A, I would also have to move that field's construction out of A.

What's the most elegant solution here? I hope I explained the problem properly. If not, please feel free to ask any questions.

An attempt at explaining the problem with code snippets:

What it's currently like:

```cpp
// constructor of class A. b_ is being constructed. field_of_a_ is initialized.
A::A() : b_{field_of_a_}, field_of_a_{5} {

}
```

What I want to avoid:

```cpp
// In the class constructing A...
int field_of_a;
B b(field_of_a);
A a(b, field_of_a);

// and inside A...
A::A(B& b, int& field_of_a) : b_{b}, field_of_a_{field_of_a} {

}
```

EDIT 1: Clarification from inside one of my comments:

*Yeah so currently B holds all kinds of timers and timer related methods. Its methods are called by A during message handling. B needs access to a queue and a few other resources located inside of A. When testing A, I want to verify that during message handling the timers are started/stopped correctly.*

Comment: Well done on your preferences for lifetime management ! Maybe something to try to compile in Rust as well ?

Comment: I don't understand what made you think about Rust tbh :'D

Comment: Well since Rust is far more careful with lifetime management, anything that works in Rust should be perfect for C++ as well. Some of the solutions you want to avoid will indeed cause trouble with the Rust compiler if I am not mistaken, which should prove your point.

Comment: Oh I see, didn't know about that :) Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing B, you should pass a factory that generates B. It still maintains the dependency injection.
The factory could be a virtual class, a function pointer, a std::function, ...

It is then up to A to use the factory. Your test would simply verify that the factory is used during construction of A.

Update : your factory should be abstract, and return an instance to the public interface of B that A requires. During testing the factory can be programmed to spawn mocked instances of B.

Also, make sure that in the class definition of A the member passed to B is declared first, then the member holding a B instance. This in order to make the first member's lifetime outlive that of B.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I want to comment on your point about using a virtual class.

Of course, when using a mock object, I'd first derive an interface of B - let's call it B_Interface.

This still leaves me with the problem of having to construct an implementation of B_Interface - namely B - in the production code. Same problem, because the B will still need 'field_of_a' as a construction parameter.

Comment: The factory could generate B directly, no need for an interface for B. It is the factory that should be tested in your case : production code -> it just calls B's constructor, test code -> it first tells gmock that B will be constructed

Comment: So you're saying "it just calls B's constructor". Your idea is to pass the 'field_of_a' variable to the factory's creation method then if I get you correctly? Because the factory will need 'field_of_a' for constructing B.

Comment: Exactly. Though I do understand this code does not explicitly test the constructor of B, it just informs that the constructor will be invoked.. The exact code will depend on what exactly it is you want/need to verify I guess.

Comment: Yeah so currently B holds all kinds of timers and timer related methods. Its methods are called by A during message handling. B needs access to a queue and a few other resources located inside of A. When testing A, I want to verify that during message handling the timers are started/stopped correctly.

Comment: Do you think a factory suits the problem I described in the comment above?

Comment: Not certain any more, no. There are tons of ways to handle this... If it's the timers that you want to test, it could be the timers that are generated from a factory. If it is the constructor of B you want to test, then B will need to become a template parameter, an abstract class or hold some reference to an abstract observer monitoring B's actions... It all really depends on your code and exactly what must be tested. Can't help you there...

Comment: The class under test is A! I want to verify, that A calls B's methods. Which is why I want to replace B with a mock object. A test would typically be: "On receiving message 'Hello', A should validate the message and stop all timers". Here I'd want to verify that A calls B's "StopAllTimers" method by using a mock object.

Comment: Then you should indeed add an interface to B, and let a factory generate an instance of std::unique_ptr<BInterface> . Let A accept such a factory at construction time. During your tests the factory can spawn a mocked B object. It will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try that out :)

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I will have to create an abstract factory?

Because my first attempt looked like this:

```cpp
class MyFactory {
 public:
  std::unique_ptr<BInterface> CreateB(int field_of_a) {
    return std::make_unique<B>(field_of_a);
  }
};
```

I pass that factory into A's constructor which then calls its CreateB method in production code.

But now I don't know how to replace B with my mock object in the tests. Should I create an abstract IMyFactory which gets passed to A and make the CreateB method virtual?

Comment: Absolutely ! I've programmed and tested a lot of code this way. I see you're really getting the point here